# VSCode Snippets: can you use variables in the definition file to influence output?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I'm working on a large snippet file as a sort of 'cheap' auto-completion workaround for a Javascript-based API. What I'd find really handy is if you could define a variable in the snippet file that could change the output of my snippets. For example:

```
GLOBAL_VARIABLE = true;

"Snippet": {
    "prefix": "snip",
    "body": [
        IF (GLOBAL_VARIABLE) { 
            "snippy(${1})"
        } ELSE {
            "snippysnippy(${1})"
        }
    ]
}
```

So depending on the value of GLOBAL_VARIABLE, the snippet output would change. Is that possible or if not does anyone have a workaround?

Comment: use the extension **Hypersnips**